# Defining an image with clickable shapes and zoom

Tags: jquery, silverlight, shapes, zooming

Good night,

My goal is to create a "virtual tree" that will contain hundreds of leaves/shapes, being each one clickable and connected to a registered user that will create content that will appear in a popup when the shape is clicked.

As i said, there will be hundreds of shapes, like the leaves of a tree, so i need a zoom option too.

One simple example that i can give is http://htwins.net/scale2/, being each zoom in like a new set of leaves/shapes

Is there any solution available or any sugestion to implement what i am describing?

I appreciate all help that can be given.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no code solution but "entry points".

1. Try it to make it as a static object in blend
2. A xaml file which includes all objects (scale, height, width, etc set to 0)
3. On click / on hover behaviour which moves the outer elements away with a increase in scale (maybe same multiplier)
4. Same thing with the inner elements which scales up on click

I would use only svg/ path images to do the scale, this reduces the size of image data volume.

This is a very tricky thing. If you have a better idea, please let me know it. :)

Regards,

- Tobias